$C^1[a,b]$ non-linear function, such that $f'' =0$ a.e.
I've been trying to come up with an example of such a function, but haven't succeeded. I was thinking of using a cantor function, since it is continuous, and its derivative is zero almost everywhere...

Anti derivative of the cantor function

Is existence of the second derivative at all points a requirement?

Your idea is correct. Let $C$ be the Cantor function, Then the function
$$
F(x)=\int_0^x C(t)\, dt
$$
Is in $C^1$ with $F’(x)=C(x)$ and $F’’(x)=0$ a.e.
